Why is CMake unable to find "magma_v2.h" when attempting to link SUNDIALS externally?
I am trying to build pion using a CMake style build system. The pion/source/microphysics/cvode_integrator.cpp file attempts to use SUNMatrix_MagmaDense and SUNLinSol_MagmaDense.
I have created a FindMAGMA.cmake file and put it in /pion/cmake/ along with FindSUNDIALS.cmake. In my CMakeLists.txt file located at /pion/ I write find_package(SUNDIALS REQUIRED) to locate my SUNDIALS installation using FindSUNDIALS.cmake. After which I have added the following lines:
    # Find MAGMA (only needed for specific SUNDIALS targets)
    find_package(MAGMA REQUIRED)
    
    # Check for SUNDIALS MAGMA-enabled targets and link them to MAGMA
    if (TARGET SUNDIALS::sunmatrixmagmadense AND TARGET SUNDIALS::sunlinsolmagmadense)
        # Link MAGMA libraries to these specific SUNDIALS targets
        target_link_libraries(SUNDIALS::sunmatrixmagmadense PRIVATE MAGMA::MAGMA)
        target_link_libraries(SUNDIALS::sunlinsolmagmadense PRIVATE MAGMA::MAGMA)
    endif()

And this what my FindMAGMA.cmake looks like:
include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)

function(find_magma_version)
    include(CheckCXXSymbolExists)
    include(CMakePushCheckState)
    set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_QUIET ON)
    CMAKE_PUSH_CHECK_STATE()

    set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_INCLUDES "${MAGMA_INCLUDE_DIR}")
    
    # Attempt to find version definitions in magma_config.h
    file(READ "${MAGMA_INCLUDE_DIR}/magma_config.h" version_header)
    
    # Extract the version number from the header file
    string(REGEX MATCH "MAGMA \\(version ([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\)" version_string_macrodef "${version_header}")
    if (version_string_macrodef)
        string(REGEX REPLACE "MAGMA \\(version ([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\)" "\\1" MAGMA_VERSION_MAJOR "${version_string_macrodef}")
        string(REGEX REPLACE "MAGMA \\(version ([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\)" "\\2" MAGMA_VERSION_MINOR "${version_string_macrodef}")
        string(REGEX REPLACE "MAGMA \\(version ([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\.([0-9]+)\\)" "\\3" MAGMA_VERSION_PATCH "${version_string_macrodef}")
        
        set(MAGMA_VERSION "${MAGMA_VERSION_MAJOR}.${MAGMA_VERSION_MINOR}.${MAGMA_VERSION_PATCH}" PARENT_SCOPE)
        set(MAGMA_VERSION_MAJOR ${MAGMA_VERSION_MAJOR} PARENT_SCOPE)
        set(MAGMA_VERSION_MINOR ${MAGMA_VERSION_MINOR} PARENT_SCOPE)
        set(MAGMA_VERSION_PATCH ${MAGMA_VERSION_PATCH} PARENT_SCOPE)
    else()
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Unable to determine MAGMA version from magma_config.h")
    endif()

    CMAKE_POP_CHECK_STATE()
endfunction()

if(MAGMA_INCLUDE_DIR)
    # If so, find the MAGMA version using the provided include directory
    find_magma_version()

    # Assume the MAGMA library has already been linked externally, 
    # no need to search for the library again.
    set(MAGMA_FOUND TRUE)

    # Optionally, create an imported target for MAGMA to be used in the project
    add_library(MAGMA::MAGMA UNKNOWN IMPORTED)
    set_target_properties(MAGMA::MAGMA PROPERTIES
        INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${MAGMA_INCLUDE_DIR}"
    )

    # Handle standard package finding
    find_package_handle_standard_args(MAGMA
        FOUND_VAR MAGMA_FOUND
        REQUIRED_VARS MAGMA_INCLUDE_DIR
        VERSION_VAR MAGMA_VERSION_STRING
    )

else()
    # If MAGMA_INCLUDE_DIR is not provided, show an error message
    message(FATAL_ERROR "MAGMA_INCLUDE_DIR is not set. Please provide the MAGMA include directory via -DMAGMA_INCLUDE_DIR=/path/to/magma/include.")
endif()

If I use the vanilla SUNDIALS linear solver and dense matrix, I do not get any linking errors and can build pion successfully. Using the MAGMA backend of SUNDIALS gives me these errors, I believe there is some error in my FindMAGMA.cmake file.
I run cmake -DSILO_INCLUDE_DIR=/mnt/e/pion/extra_libraries/include       -DSILO_LIBRARY=/mnt/e/pion/extra_libraries/lib/libsilo.so       -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/mnt/e/sundials/install -DMAGMA_INCLUDE_DIR=/mnt/e/magma-2.8.0/include .. from /pion/build/ and then make -j$(nproc) which gives me the following error:
[ 11%] Building CXX object source/ics/CMakeFiles/ics.dir/icgen_base.cpp.o
In file included from /mnt/e/pion/source/microphysics/cvode_integrator.h:84,
                 from /mnt/e/pion/source/microphysics/MPv10/MPv10.h:41,
                 from /mnt/e/pion/source/microphysics/MPv10/MPv10.cpp:22:
/mnt/e/sundials/install/include/sundials/../sunlinsol/sunlinsol_magmadense.h:33:10: fatal error: magma_v2.h: No such file or directory
   33 | #include <magma_v2.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [source/microphysics/MPv10/CMakeFiles/mpv10.dir/build.make:76: source/microphysics/MPv10/CMakeFiles/mpv10.dir/MPv10.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....


Also, I can compile the script located at /sundials/examples/cvode/magma/ by changing its name to a .cu extension and compiling with the nvcc compiler. So SUNDIALS has successfully been built with ENABLE_MAGMA and ENABLE_CUDA both set to ON.

target_link_libraries(SUNDIALS::sunmatrixmagmadense PRIVATE MAGMA::MAGMA) - Is this (and following) lines are ever executed? You could add message calls to that branch for confirm that. For me, those lines are just wrong, as SUNDIALS::sunmatrixmagmadense is an IMPORTED target, so it cannot have PRIVATE linkage; only INTERFACE one is allowed.

use make VERBOSE=1. that will show you the exact compilation step. From there you'll be able to see if you're defining the correct directory for magma_v2.h
